# SQL Query not returning all users when I try to find details across multiple tables with multiple where conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in a database with user data from a SAS where users make progress across multiple metrics including time spent on a module and completing a module.  I tried to run a query that found all the metrics I was looking for in one script.  The script ignored any users with null values for one condition (completed modules) and then added additional data to the remaining users.

This is the combined query:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.full_name,
    u.email,
    CAST(SUM(m1.time) AS float) / 60 AS Hours,
    COUNT(DISTINCT m.module_ID) AS Modules_Completed
FROM
    users u 
INNER JOIN 
    organizations_users_matches o ON u.id = o.user_id --(Intermediate Table that associates user with organization)
INNER JOIN 
    organizations o1 ON o1.id = o.organization_id 
INNER JOIN  
    module_assignments m ON m.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN 
    module_content_user_interactions m1 ON m1.user_id = u.id 
WHERE
    m1.created_at BETWEEN '07-01-2021' AND '01-12-2022' 
    AND m.completed_at BETWEEN '07-01-2021' AND '01-12-2022' 
    AND u.role IN (2, 3) 
    AND u.active is true 
    AND o1.id = X
GROUP BY 
    u.id
```

I also tried with Left and Right Outer Joins to see if that would solve the issue, but it didn't work either.

When the scripts are broken into two separate scripts, the correct results are given.
I.E. One script covers the sum of time with the where condition "m1.created_at BETWEEN '07-01-2021' and '01-12-2022'." The other script covered the count of modules with the where condition "m.completed_at BETWEEN '07-01-2021' and '01-12-2022'"

Is there a way to get the system to return the null values for the modules completed column rather than skipping them and forcing them into the other users with completed modules?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your joins do need to be a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. Which ones depends on more data than we can see in the question.

What I can say for sure is if all of the joins are `LEFT JOIN` I can **guarantee** you will see every user with a record that matches the final `WHERE` clause. Therefore start there, and start by removing elements from the `WHERE` clause until you see every user. Then, as you add conditions back to the `WHERE` clause, think about why they might cause missing user records to be excluded.